# Round decimal value to nearest 5 or 0 amount

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a web application that will apply a percentage markup to a product, but the percentage will be specified by a user.  For example, the user can indicate they want to mark up a product 5%, 9%, 23%, etc.  My problem is, the product price will change as well, and in doing so, end up giving ugly values ($1462.72)

As a result, my users are hoping that we can round the value to the nearest 5\0 value.  So if my marked up product price is $1462.72, it would round up to $1465.  $1798.02 on the other hand would round up to an even $1800.

Using VB\C#, how can I go about rounding these values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To round to an arbitrary modulus you can create a function like:

```
public decimal Round(decimal source, decimal modulus)
{
    return (Math.Round(source / modulus) * modulus);
}
```

and use it in this way:

```
decimal rounded = Round(1798.02m , 5.0m);  // yields 1800.0
decimal rounded = Round(1462.72m , 5.0m);  // yields 1465.0
decimal rounded = Round(2481.23m , 5.0m);  // yields 2480.0
```

Note that `Math.Round` by default rounds midpoint values to the closest *even* number (e.g. 1.5 and 2.5 would both "round" to 2.  In your case, the effect is that any numbers that are exactly between a 0 and 5 number (i.e. 2.5, 7.5) would be rounded to the closest 10:

```
decimal rounded = Round(1697.50m , 5.0m);  // yields 1700.0
decimal rounded = Round(1702.50m , 5.0m);  // yields 1700.0
```

If you want to *always* round UP on the midpoint just specify that in `Round`:

```
return (Math.Round(source / modulus, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * modulus);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.op_modulus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to calculate the adjustment needed.

```
decimal price = 1798.02;
decimal adjustment = price % 5.0;
if(adjustment != 0) //so we don't round up already round numbers
{
  price = (price - adjustment) + 5;
}
```

This will bring it up to the next multiple of 5.